# Como mostrar los checkbox marcados en laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, formularios, laravel-8

Tengo el siguiente formulario, que contiene un multiple checkbox, en el que guardo en mi base de datos, los valores marcados. Hasta ahi bien, como puedo mostrar los valores que estaban ya marcados en el checkbox correspondiente de la forma adecuada ?

El texto se guarda así en la base de datos:

```
["contacto","galeria"]
```

He conseguido mostrar correctamente los checkbox marcados pero el problema, es que se me repiten tantas veces como datos guardados tenga:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @foreach($config->category as $value)
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="contacto" name="category[]" @if ($value == "contacto") checked @endif> Contacto</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="tiempo" name="category[]" @if ($value == "tiempo") checked @endif> El Tiempo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="galeria" name="category[]" @if ($value == "galeria") checked @endif> Galeria</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="mercadillo" name="category[]" @if ($value == "mercadillo") checked @endif> Mercadillo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="noticias" name="category[]" @if ($value == "noticias") checked @endif> Noticias</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="webcams" name="category[]" @if ($value == "webcams") checked @endif> Webcams</label>
  @endforeach
```

Se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado a hacer con todos los checkbox del listado esto, cambiado contacto por el nombre que le corresponde:

```
@if(in_array("contacto", $config->category)) checked @endif
```

Tambien he probado:

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" value="tiempo" name="category[]" @foreach($config->category as $value) @if($value == "tiempo") checked @endif @endforeach> El Tiempo</label>
```

Pero cuando hay mas de un checkbox marcado, si solo insertas en una linea este codigo si muestra la página con ese checkbox marcado o no, pero si hay mas de uno y insertas las lineas en todos los checkboxs para que muestren si estan marcados o no sale el siguiente error:

```
ErrorException
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\proyecto\resources\views\configs\config.blade.php)
```

Comment: Que es lo que contiene `$config->category`?

Comment: @JuanRivera esto ["contacto","galeria"] los checkbox marcados

Comment: Entonces, si contiene un array y estas haciendo un `foreach`, en la iteracion ya estas tomando el valor interno, por lo cual podrias hacer `@if( $value == 'contacto' ) checked @endif`. Esto por cada tipo(tiempo, galeria, etc)

Comment: justo acabo de editar la pregunta con lo mismo pero ahora el problema es que se repite tantas veces como items marcados tengo, ya que esta dentro del foreach

Comment: Entonces como quieres que salga? Solo una vez Contacto, tiempo,etc y no 3 veces...con los items marcados?

Comment: @JuanRivera si quiero que se vea una sola linea con su correspondiente checkbox marcado si asi es

Comment: Entonces esta bien tu codigo, quita los `inputs` fuera del `foreach` y cambia los `@ifs` por `@if(in_array("contacto", $config->category)) checked @endif`

Comment: @JuanRivera si hay mas de un checkbox parece que sale el siguiente error  ErrorException
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: @WinterIsback bro lo lograstes solucionar?

Answer (score 2):

Sólo debes imprimir una vez cada checkbox dentro del for.

```
@foreach($config->category as $value)
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $value }}" name="category[]" @if ($value == ...) checked @endif>{{ $value }}</label>
@endforeach
```

Ahora bien, tal y como comenté en otra de tus preguntas, aparentemente no tienes una tabla en donde guardar todas las categorías existentes y una en donde guardar sólo las seleccionadas.

Mi recomendación es que envíes dos arrays a la vista, una que contenga todos los no seleccionados (o todos) y otra con sólo los seleccionados.

Es decir, en tu controlador defines un array que pasarás a la vista:

```
$allCategories = ['contacto', 'galeria', 'mercadillo', ...];
```

Ese array debes enviarlo a tu vista, luego sólo debes recorrerlo con el for. Ojo aquí, en total tendrías dos arrays:

- `$config->category`: El cual contendrá sólo las categorías seleccionadas.
- `$allCategories`: El cual contendrá todas las categorías.

Por lo que tu for debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
@foreach($allCategories as $category)
     <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{ $category }}" name="category[]" @if (in_array($category, $config->category)) checked @endif>{{ $category }}</label>
@endforeach
```

¿Por qué utilizarías `in_array()`? Simple, debes buscar si el valor de cada categoría se encuentra dentro del array de los seleccionados, si está entonces significa que está seleccionado (obviamente), y por eso debes ponerle un checked.

Otra manera, no recomendada, de trabajar teniendo sólo lo que tienes, es utilizando `switch` en lugar de un `if`. Ya que quieres verificar si un valor se encuentra dentro de un arreglo de valores.